# jQuery chosen Multi-select with count

Tags: multi-select, jquery-chosen

Currently, using chosen version 1.1.0

In multi-select

1. I want to show only the first selected and then count.
2. When I click on any selected item then it will be deselected

I did something by writing some custom code by extending the chosen but I will be happy if I can get any stable plugin

[image]